# How to search using a regular expression that returns only one result per line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to search text files for lines with at least 4 upper case letters, but it doesn't matter what the letters are.

Currently I have been using [A-Z]{4} And selecting match case. It returns the results I need but if there are any multiples of 4 in the line, it returns multiple results.

So if I have a line like below:

```
 713,6=INTERSECTION WITH ATLAS PIPELINE,
```

Then my search will yield 7 separate results instead of just one for that line.

Is there a way to just search for 4 upper case letters per line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the following instead:

```
^.*[A-Z]{4}.*$
```

That will match a complete line. If you need to capture the match then use parentheses around `[A-Z]{4}` e.g.:

```
^.*([A-Z]{4}).*$
```